# Check if word occurs more than once in a text document

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

Basically, I need to check a file to see whether a username occurs more than once and if it does, place that username into a different file.

In the end the script is meant to check every 3 seconds whether a user is logged in more than once and if they are, add their name to a file called user.deny.

here's what I have basically at the moment:

```
who -q > temp.file
if [ user occurs more than once in temp.file ]; then
that username > user.deny
fi
```

I just want to know a way to check the temp file for all words/names which occur more than once. I can't use `grep` because that requires a pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any username or a particular username? you can grep for a particular username using  grep "username" temp.file | wc -c. 'wc -c will give you a word count'

Comment: I'm looking for all usernames.

So if there is john and anne logged on twice, both of their names go into the file.

if I was searching for a particular name i would use grep "john" and it wouldn't be a problem, but I don't know what names are going to be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `sort`, `uniq` and `awk`:

```
who | awk '{print $1} '| sort | uniq -c | awk '{ if($1 > 1) {print $2} }' >> user.deny
```

If you want to do some checking before adding the username, you can wrap it in a loop:

```
for u in $(who | awk '{print $1} '| sort | uniq -c | awk '{ if($1 > 1) {print $2} }')
do
  grep "$u" user.deny || echo "$u" >> user.deny
done
```

Comment: It's working pretty well at the moment except it will constantly add the user over and over.

Would a solution be to do an if saying if the product of your code already exists inside of user.deny, don't add?

Comment: Perfect now. Thanks heaps!

Comment: No probs, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

### Using Ruby

```
$ who |
  ruby -ane 'BEGIN { h = Hash.new(0) };
             h[$F[0]] += 1;
             END { puts h.select { |k,v| v > 1 }.keys.join ?\n }' > user.deny
```